# Can't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to launch gdb, from toolchain, from Visual Studio Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-debugger

I tried on both:

1. Windows 10, VSCode 1.52.1, Remote - WSL v0.52.0, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
2. Virtual Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, VSCode 1.52.1

And wasn't able to run GDB from VS Code, because I need to specify LD_LIBRARY_PATH for it.
I can run it from console as:
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/toolchain/vararm/lib /opt/toolchain/vararm/bin/arm-linux-gdb`
or

```sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/toolchain/vararm/lib
# doesn't work without export.
/opt/toolchain/vararm/bin/arm-linux-gdb
```

and it's working fine.

I tried to use

- "environment"
- "linux" { "environment" }
- "env"
- "additionalSOLibSearchPath"
- "envFile"

but not a single one was working.
I changed miDebuggerPath to my custom script that is printing env and there was no LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
After some testing I found out, that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is somehow used AFTER gdb started to load other libraries, but it's not used to start GDB itself.

In the end I make workaround with script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                               
#/opt/toolchain/vararm/bin/arm-linux-gdb.sh
# Set Toolchain's path before running debugger
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/toolchain/vararm/lib
exec /opt/toolchain/vararm/bin/arm-linux-gdb "$@"
```

**But I would like to be able to run GDB from VS Code without any workaround, can somebody help me?**

My configuration in launch.json:

```json
{
            "name": "[vararm] 192.168.168.112",
            /*"preLaunchTask": "[vararm] 192.168.168.112",*/
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/../target/vararm/bin/sqlite_checkpoint",
            /*"args": [ "-c", "${workspaceFolder}/../target/conf/sqlite_checkpoint.cfg" ],*/
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            /*"envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/vararm.env",*/
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name":"LD_LIBRARY_PATH",
                    "value":"${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/toolchain/vararm/lib",
                },
                {
                    "name":"LD_TEST",
                    "value": "LD_TEST"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            /*"additionalSOLibSearchPath": "/opt/toolchain/vararm/lib",*/
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "192.168.168.112:54321",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/opt/toolchain/vararm/bin/arm-linux-gdb.sh",
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true, "moduleLoad": true, "exceptions": true, "trace": true }
        }
```

Comment: I think `env` is for the target, not the debugger. Maybe something like setting `muDebuggerPath` to `/usr/bin/env` and setting `miDebuggerArgs` appropriately would work? I'm not sure it's much cleaner than a wrapper script though. You might want to send them a feature request if you want something more convenient.

Comment: I tried setting env in miDebuggerPath or miDebuggerArgs  but failed. Can't use any arguments or combine 2 apps in any way in miDebuggerPath 'cos it will not pass validation. Also first argument is always --interpreter=mi and after that it's miDebuggerArgs, don't even know how stop that.

Comment: I think you're probably going to want to open an issue for [MIEngine](https://github.com/microsoft/MIEngine) to add debugger env support. I don't see any obvious way around this.